# Copy only certain columns from one table to other and insert defa

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I couldn't get any answer googling this question. 
I have 2 sql tables,  `

- Table1 (Id1, Name) and
- Table2(Id2, Number)

I would like to copy only one column 'Id1' from table1 to 'Id2' column of table2, while inserting constant value to the Number column.

How can I modify my sql query to achieve this

- INSERT INTO Table2
           (Id2)
               SELECT id1 FROM Table1;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Id2, Number)
    SELECT id1, <constant value goes here>
    FROM Table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking this a step further an option here would be add a trigger on Table1 to insert into Table2 after insert.

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Table1_CopyId1ColToId2Table2] ON [dbo].[Table1]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(ID2, Number)
SELECT ID1, <const value> FROM inserted
```

END

You could also take advantage of after update of the row as well using a trigger. This guarantees even if the row is edited outside the app the trigger still fires.